# Flutter: run function on theme change

Tags: flutter

I need to run a function every time the system theme changes from dark to light or vice-versa. Is there a way to fire something off whenever this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this blog , I guess you can put your function in **didChangePlatformBrightness()** method.
https://thiagoevoa.medium.com/change-flutter-app-theme-according-to-the-system-theme-mode-c4a63d05128f